# Loading only relevant section of image into RAM

Tags: node.js, svg, snap.svg, graphicsmagick

In my website I have a viewer that loads huge 200mb pictures (millionsXmillions of pixels). 
With that, on screen the client never sees more than say 1600x900 pixels at a time. 
Loading the full image seems to be a huge toll on the browser, actually often my tab crashes when I try to load a picture that is too big.

1. How do I go about serving only the visible part of the image? (serving a section of image by coordinates)
2. If the image was scrolled left by 100px, I want to serve the new 100px only, not the entire 1600x900 section that includes those 100px. Meaning, that the client needs to know what section it already has, and only requests for the new section that it lacks.
3. I would like to unload parts of the image from the client after a certain period of time.

(Yes, very similar to the way google maps work)

Any tips on what to read? where to look? What approach I should attempt?

I am using node.js with graphicsmagick.

Comment: This might get you started... http://libvips.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/making-deepzoom-zoomify-and-google-maps.html

Comment: Thanks! I was also looking into this: http://www.maptiler.com/